# Compare values of two timestamps and insert them into results based on a pre-defined structure within a concat function

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

**[DB-Fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=fddcf2ca844cbd96f088f6c3ea2e92eb)**

```
CREATE TABLE operations (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    time_stamp DATE,
    product VARCHAR(255),
    plan_week VARCHAR(255),
    quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO operations
(time_stamp, product, plan_week, quantity
)
VALUES 
("2020-01-01", "Product_A", "CW01", "125"),
("2020-01-01", "Product_B", "CW01", "300"),
("2020-01-01", "Product_C", "CW08", "700"),
("2020-01-01", "Product_D", "CW01", "900"),
("2020-01-01", "Product_G", "CW05", "600"),

("2020-03-15", "Product_A", "CW01", "570"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_C", "CW02", "150"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_E", "CW02", "325"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_G", "CW01", "482");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
time_stamp     product     plan_week      quantity         plan_week_switch
2020-01-01     Product_A      CW01           125                  no
2020-03-15     Product_A      CW01           570                  no
2020-01-01     Product_B      CW01           300                  no
2020-01-01     Product_C      CW08           700              CW08-to-CW02
2020-03-15     Product_C      CW02           150              CW08-to-CW02
2020-01-01     Product_D      CW01           900                  no
2020-03-15     Product_E      CW02           325                  no
2020-01-01     Product_G      CW05           600              CW05-to-CW01
2020-03-15     Product_G      CW01           482              CW05-to-CW01
```

---

In the above table I compare two `timestamps` and check if the `plan_week` has switched between the both `timestamps`. 
If yes I want that in column `plan_week_switch` it is described from which `plan_week` to which `plan_week` it has changed.

Currently, I am using this query:

```
SELECT 
time_stamp,
product,
plan_week,
quantity,

 (CASE WHEN MIN(plan_week) over (PARTITION BY product) = MAX(plan_week) over (PARTITION BY product)
 THEN 'no' ELSE CONCAT(CAST(MIN(plan_week) over (PARTITION by product) AS CHAR), '-to-',
 MAX(plan_week) over (PARTITION BY product)) END) AS plan_week_switch

FROM operations
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 2,1;
```

The issue is that in case of `Product_G` this query inserts `CW01-to-CW05` instead of `CW05-to-CW01` into column `plan_week_switch.` 
However, I always want that the week of the **older** `timestamp` **appears as the first week** and the week of the **younger** `timestamp` as the **second week**.

What do I need to change in my query to achieve this?

Comment: Isn't there a case that there are 3 or more consecutive switches for a product?

Comment: No. Each product has exactly one week assigned per timestamp. Therefore, there can only be two switches.

Comment: Then Akina's answer will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT time_stamp,
                     product,
                     plan_week,
                     quantity,
                     FIRST_VALUE(plan_week) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY time_stamp DESC) first_plan,
                     FIRST_VALUE(plan_week) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY time_stamp ASC) last_plan
              FROM operations )
SELECT time_stamp,
       product,
       plan_week,
       quantity,
       CASE WHEN first_plan = last_plan
            THEN 'no'
            ELSE CONCAT(first_plan, '-to-', last_plan) 
            END plan_week_switch
FROM cte;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=8f8fbf6c7c11978c2fce1aba7f9c8e73)

> The query still inserts CW01-to-CW05 instead of CW05-to-CW01 for Product_G

Use backward window definitions:

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT time_stamp,
                     product,
                     plan_week,
                     quantity,
                     FIRST_VALUE(plan_week) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY time_stamp ASC) first_plan,
                     FIRST_VALUE(plan_week) OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY time_stamp DESC) last_plan
              FROM operations )
SELECT time_stamp,
       product,
       plan_week,
       quantity,
       CASE WHEN first_plan = last_plan
            THEN 'no'
            ELSE CONCAT(first_plan, '-to-', last_plan) 
            END plan_week_switch
FROM cte;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=a656d6a42a793bc0a0e55b5f685cd41d)

Comment: The query still inserts CW01-to-CW05 instead of CW05-to-CW01 for Product_G

Comment: @Michi Swap ASC and DESC in window definitions if the order is wrong.

Comment: Just for my own documentation: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=ebc923ef7125a762b92f857a40f20b77

Comment: Also for my own documenation: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f4555ff6cceec1e5b2e38a378c7e450b